# https : url up/down status checking

Tags: bash, unix, tomcat, https, wap

We having https wap server, Its some times not responding and which is deployed on rhel 6.1 64bit. Wap server running in apache tomcat. I tried netstat and ping and telnet all result are fine. but through browser it not responding.due to https all are fail to identifies the reason. how check the status of that ip through bash script whether that alwys responding or not.

Comment: `how check the status of that ip through bash script.` ping is enough for you like `ping 256.256.256.256 ; echo $?`

Comment: Ping,netstat and telnet results are fine. But accessing server through browser that time its not responding.

Comment: try `wget` or `curl` then?